# XDG0012: The Member is Not Recognized Or is Not Accessible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, controls, windows-forms-designer

These errors appear for the first time and with the creation of any Designer.xmal! Previously these errors did not appear, I tried many solutions but no avail.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq3uI.png)

Comment: Designer.xmal? Are you sure it's a Winforms project, rather than WPF or UWP?

Comment: its UiPath Custom Activity Project

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the Visual studio XAML editor. Close the Visual studio and re-open it to fix this issue.